# Booleans not working correctly

Tags: php, mysqli

Programming a function to see if a user is 'active' or not.

```
function user_active($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
$query = mysqli_query($_POST['x'], "SELECT * FROM users");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if ($row['username'] === $username and $row['active'] === 1) {

    return true;
    } else {
    return false;

           }
    }
```

and then....

```
if (user_active($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'You have not activated your account. Please check your
    email to activate your account.';
```

It only works when I test against $username but when I include $row['active'] === 1 it stops working.

Comment: can you dump the $row['active'](var_dump())?

Comment: `$row['active'] === 1` probable because `$row['active']` is a string.

Comment: What is the data type of `$row['active']`? If it's a string, `=== 1` will not work. Try `== 1` or `=== '1'`.

Comment: it is a string, I've tried both == 1 and === '1' but when i change the value of active in my table, it still allows me to log in

Comment: this solution will not scale once you have more than one user.  you should put this into the mysql logic and use a query similar to "SELECT active FROM users WHERE user.username = ? AND user.active = 1" (use params to pass username in as the ?).  then if you get a row back then you have an active user.  otherwise you'll have to loop through all the users in the php layer.

Answer (score 1):

`===` checks for an identical match, meaning

```
$x === 1
```

will check if `$x` is an integer with the value of 1.

`==` checks for equality in the value only, so

```
$x == 1
```

will check if `$x` has a value of 1, whether it is a string or integer or something else, like a boolean `true`.

Try changing your statement to

```
$row['active'] == 1
```

or, if you know your variable is a string,

```
$row['active'] === '1'
```

---

Reference:

**$a == $b**....*Equal*....**TRUE** if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.

**$a === $b**....*Identical*....**TRUE** if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Tried this, then switched the value of `active` in the table from 1 to 0 and it still allowed me to log in

Comment: `var_dump($row['active'])`. What is the value and type?

Comment: the value is 1 and the type is string, even when I change the value to 0 in mysql table

Comment: The value is 1 even when you change it to 0 in th db? If so, that's your problem. Find out why your query is not returning the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The difference between == and === is 
'===' check for equality between left side and right side with datatype too when comparing using '===' if data type is not equal then it returns false.

```
function user_active($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
$query = mysqli_query($_POST['x'], "SELECT * FROM users");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if ($row['username'] === $username and $row['active'] == 1) {

    return true;
    } else {
    return false;

           }
    }
```